# Updating Local Database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, local-database

I have a problem regarding updating local database with Entity framework.

I'll show you just small basic example of a problem, and I will type it literally, so anyone who reads this can see if I forgot something.

In a newely created WPF project, I added New Item -> Local Database,
and then Dataset -> Finish and in that database I'v created a table with 2 columns: ID and name.

Then Add -> New Item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model for that base

I have made a button with a click event which should add a new values in table columns, but
nothing happends in the database. This is the code I have written:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Database1Entities DbTest = new Database1Entities();

        Table1 table = new Table1
        {               
            Name = "John"               
        };

        DbTest.AddToTable1(table);
        DbTest.SaveChanges();              
    }
```

When I execute program, in debug I have the following error:
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

I don't understand what's wrong, because when I do the same thing with Database created in SQL server, and connecting to VS2010 via EDM, everything works perfectly.

Comment: "See the inner exception for details" - what prevents you to see inner exception and post it here, you don't understand, what it means?

Comment: You most likely didn't make the ID column an auto-incrementing [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) value, but as @Dennis says, please provide the InnerException. Or read and try to understand what it's saying.